# Overlapping Boxes

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to keep the boxes inside my container id, but for some reason they keep overlapping on the right hand side. I'm new to this so please go easy on me.

[Overlapping Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twoaD.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Block-Level</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #container{
  /* Auto margins used for centering elements horizontally */
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  /* Box dimensions */
  width: 1000px;
  /* Colour of box */
  background-color: #AA4639;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
  }
  .box1{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #81BBC9;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing margin, padding from sides but not top/bottom.  As in:

```
/* vertical | horizontal */
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 5px 0;
```

See demo:

```css
#container {
  /* Auto margins used for centering elements horizontally */  
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* Box dimensions */
  width: 500px;
  /* Colour of box */
  background-color: #AA4639;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 5px 0; /* here */
  padding: 5px 0; /* here */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow i cannot believe it was that simple haha. Thanks for the response.

Comment: glad I could help... :)

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation yet for it to be displayed, but rest assured once I do I shall up-vote again

Comment: Thanks a lot, you will most likely see me asking many more question in the future haha.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is with `box-sizing` and `margin`.  The default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`, so when you set the width, that won't be including any `padding`s, `border-width`s, or `margin`s.  When you set it to `border-box`, the padding gets put inside the width of the element.

With margin, however, it's still outside the border-box, so it pushes against its container on the left.  That's what causes the overlap to happen.

By removing the margins on the outside of the boxes and only preserving the margins between boxes, we eliminate this issue.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  /* Auto margins used for centering elements horizontally */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Box dimensions */
  width: 1000px;
  /* Colour of box */
  background-color: #AA4639;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box1:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because when you declare width: 100% in box1, the width becomes the same as your container! Try statically assigning the width, or changing it to a value less than 100%, like 98% as below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Block-Level</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #container{
  /* Auto margins used for centering elements horizontally */
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  /* Box dimensions */
  width: 1000px;
  /* Colour of box */
  background-color: #AA4639;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
  }
  .box1{
   width: 98%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #81BBC9;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I did do this prior when I was looking at other methods and indeed it worked, but I need to keep the width at 100% as I have been asked to do so in my assignment. I removed the margin and padding from the .box1 class which also worked to keep the box inside the container id but the horizontal gap between each box is to thin.

Comment: @hymcode in that case, only remove the margin and padding from the sides but not from the top/bottom.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Thanks for the link. I shall check it out.